# WCF REST service not recognizing URI parameters

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest

I am trying to develop an android app that is interacting with WCF services. I looked at the formats possible to send, but the service doesnt seem to be recognizing the parameters and calling the assigned function.

**WCF code:**

```
public interface IEmployeeService
     {

    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetEmployees/{LocationId}/{SessionId}/{CompanyId}", 
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    List<Employee> GetEmployees(string LocationId,string SessionId,string CompanyId);}
```

**Android Side code:**

```
          DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);

                HttpEntity responseEntity = execute.getEntity();


                Reader employeeReader = new InputStreamReader(execute.getEntity().getContent());
                char[] buffer = new char[(int) execute.getEntity().getContentLength()];
                //fill the buffer by the help of reader
                employeeReader.read(buffer);
                //close the reader streams
                employeeReader.close();
```

The URI it generates is something like this: `EmployeeService.svc/GetEmployees/1311000032/2014/1312`

and I also tried the other format (eg `/GetEmployees/?LocationId={LocationId}&SessionId={SessionId}`)

I have checked the service using a console application and passing parameters to the reference of the service gives the correct result. But using the URI returns nothing.

Comment: Have you tried consuming web services using Volley?

Comment: Nope, could you link me to someplace where I could get to know how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the Problem. It was with the web.config file. The service name was incorrect. How stupid of me.